# Nodejs express promise.all().then() is not synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I'm building a little app using Nodejs express where I update/delete some data. After it did the update/delete, I want to return the data from the database again. I'm using promise.all() because I want to either have everything succeed or fail together.

My problem is that it's not being run synchronously. Every now and then my code returns the data before the update/delete has happend.

Here is an example:

```js
const save = async (houseId, personIds, pets, petsToDelete) => {
    let dbActions = []

    personIds.forEach((personId) => {
        pets.forEach((pet) => {
            pet.ownerId = personId
        })
        dbActions.push(
            PetRepository.deletePets(personId, petsToDelete),
            PetRepository.updatePets(personId, pets),
        )
    })

    await Promise.all(dbActions)
    let promiseResult = await Promise.all([
           PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
    ])

    return promiseResult
}
```

The issue is that PetRepository.findByHouse is sometimes returning data before all dbActions in the loop were executed/completed.

I thought adding them to an array and using that array in a Promise.all outside the loop would fix the issue, but it didn't. Any ideas?

How save() is called:

```js
    const promiseResponseHandler = (req, res, promise) => {
        promise.then(successResponse(req, res)).catch(...errorhandling...)
    }

    App.put('save/:houseId', (req, res) => {
        promiseResponseHandler(req, res, PetService.save(req.params.houseId, req.body[0], req.body[1], req.body[2]))
    })
```

Update: repository functions

```js
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')
Mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

Mongoose.connection.on('open', () => Logger.info('Db connection established'))
let connectionString

connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${Config.MONGO_HOST}?retryWrites=true`

connection = Mongoose.connect(
    connectionString,
    {
        user: Config.MONGO_USER,
        pass: Config.MONGO_PW,
        dbName: Config.MONGO_DB,
        reconnectTries: 3,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }
).catch((err) => {
    Logger.error(err)
})

const deletePets = async (personId, petsToDelete) => {
    if (petsToDelete.length > 0) {
        await Pet.bulkWrite(
            petsToDelete.map((petId) => {
                deleteMany: {
                    filter: { personId: personId, petId: petId}
                }
            })
        )
    }
}

const updatePets = async (personId, pets) => {
    if (pets.length > 0) {
        await Pet.bulkWrite(
            pets.map((pet) => ({
                updateOne: {
                    filter: { personId: pet.personId, petId: petId },
                    update: { 
                        $set: { name: pet.name },
                        $setOnInsert: { 
                            petId: pet.petId, 
                            personId: personId,
                            houseId: pet.houseId
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }))
        )
    }
}

module.exports = { deletePets, updatePets }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `async`/`await` if you're not using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using thenables (callbacks) to approach this problem. It would be easier to use async/await. In order to be able to await the `Promise.all`, you would need to define `save` as an asynchronous function, like so:

```js
const save = async (houseId, personIds, pets, petsToDelete) => {
    let dbActions = []

    personIds.forEach((personId) => {
        pets.forEach((pet) => {
            pet.ownerId = personId
        })
        dbActions.push(
            PetRepository.deletePets(personId, petsToDelete),
            PetRepository.updatePets(personId, pets),
        )
    })

    await Promise.all(dbActions)
    let promiseResult = await PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
    return promiseResult
}
```

You would then proceed to await the save in order to make sure it concludes before you continue.
Of course, you could do this with callbacks too, passing it to the save method, and calling it with your final response, like so:

```js
const save = (houseId, personIds, pets, petsToDelete, callback) => {
    let dbActions = []

    personIds.forEach((personId) => {
        pets.forEach((pet) => {
            pet.ownerId = personId
        })
        dbActions.push(
            PetRepository.deletePets(personId, petsToDelete),
            PetRepository.updatePets(personId, pets),
        )
    })

    Promise.all(dbActions).then(()=>
        // callback gets called with the response of the promise
        PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId }).then(callback)
    )
}
```

You do have to keep in mind that you can't just assign a promise to a variable and expect it to be the result. If you do:

```js
let result = Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
```

`result` will contain a promise, so in order to get the value you'll either have to `await` it (inline) or `then` it (callback)

Comment: I tried replacing the thenables with the async solution you proposed, but the problem still persists. I've added an example of how I call the save() function. The promiseResult still returns some data that should've been updated or deleted in the dbActions promise list.

Comment: Are you making sure to `await` wherever you invoke a promise?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with the new implementation

Comment: That all looks good, the only thing that comes to mind is if those repository functions are returning promises properly 

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question agian with the repository functions code, could you have a look? In the db everything is updated as expected, it's just that in the Save function `PetRepository.findByHouse` is returned prematurely before everything in dbActions is finished. I've tried everything to make sure it returns after dbActions, but it still occurs.

Comment: The problem is that those functions are not returning promises. It should work if you make them `async` like you did with `save` and `await` the `bulkWrite`

Answer (score 1):

function `then` expects function to be provided but you provide just assignment and this assignment executes in a same time. So instead of

```
Promise.all(dbActions).then( 
        (promiseResult = Promise.all([
            PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
        ]))
    )
```

write at least

```
Promise.all(dbActions).then( () =>
        (promiseResult = Promise.all([
            PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
        ]))
    )
```

but even this code looks strange. Why you put one promise inside Promise.all, and what do you expect to get in promiseResult - promise or result?

May be you meant

```
Promise.all(dbActions).then( () =>
  PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
).then(res => { promiseResult = res })
```

then in promiseResult you will get Pet instance itself

Comment: The reason there was a single promise inside the Promise.all is because my initial example had 2 promises, but for explanations sake I left it out. I'll try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found what has been causing `PetRepository.findByHouse` to return prematurely.

```js
const save = (houseId, personIds, pets, petsToDelete) => {
    let dbActions = []

    personIds.forEach((personId) => {
        pets.forEach((pet) => {
            pet.ownerId = personId
        })
        dbActions.push(
            PetRepository.deletePets(personId, petsToDelete),
            PetRepository.updatePets(personId, pets),
        )
    })

    return Promise.all(dbActions).then(() => { // this is the correct way to wait for dbActions
                                               // and then return findByHouse(...)
            return PetRepository.findByHouse({ houseId: houseId })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out and let you know if it worked

Comment: Nope it still happens for some reason... If I look into the DB everything updated correctly, but for some reason `PetRepository.findByHouse` is still returning prematurely.